# Given that the triangle alongside is equilateral, ￼￼find a and b.

Tags: triangles, word-problem

Given that the triangle alongside is equilateral,
￼￼find a and b.

First side equals to (b+2)
The second side equals to (a+4)
The third side equals to (4a-b)

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I have no Idea so far, since we just started working on this in class. We have to solve this using pairs of linear equations.

I assume we have to write down two equations and solve them simultaneously.

Comment: What is the definition of an equilateral triangle?

Comment: All of the sides are equal

Answer (score 1):

**So** b+2 = a+4 = 4a-b
With these 3 equations we can say

b=a+2

3a=b+4

b=2a-1

**Hence**

2a-1=a+2

**And**  a=3,  b=5

If you don't understand I can add more steps, just say what is not clear.

Comment: This is great! Everything is clear now. I finally understand how to put variables into an equation.

Thank you :)

Comment: cool :) I was afraid of being to fast in my explications.